# Efficient mapping of 2d array

Tags: java, performance, optimization

This may sound like a very basic problem but I could not find a satisfying answer yet.

I need to map an array of values to a 2d array of indices, approximately 60 times a second. In order to reduce the workload I want to find the most efficient way to do so.
Currently what I am doing (for the sake of the example):

```
int[] COLOR_MAP = new int[] { 0xFFFFFF, 0xD3D3D3, 0xA9A9A9, 0x000000 };
int[][] indices = new int[][] {
        {0, 1, 2, 3},
        {3, 2, 1, 0},
        {2, 1, 3, 3},
        {1, 1, 2, 2},
};
int[][] colors = new int[4][4];

for (int y = 0; y < 4; ++y)
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x)
                colors[y][x] = COLOR_MAP[indices[y][x]];
```

Is there an equivalent or something "scala-like" with maps ? What's the most efficient way of getting rid of the nested loop ?

Comment: "I need to map an array of values ... approximately 60 times a second." Which array changes 60 times a second, the COLOR_MAP or the indices?

Comment: The indices. The nested loop is called at a 60Hz rate to create a buffered image given the indices array and the color map

Comment: How do the indices change?  Is it less than 10% per frame?  In other words, can you create a sparse List of index changes and just update the colors values that actually changed in the frame?

Comment: Most likely every pixel will change, even slightly

Comment: Then @Peter Walser's answer is likely to be the best you can do.  Just make sure your indices and colors matrix sizes are powers of two.

Comment: 60x a second is really nothing; especially not for number crunching logic like this with small arrays. Perhaps a good thing, before optimizing the code, is to determine if it actually is a performance problem. And don't measure only what you can see in the JVM. So perhaps good to use a tool like async-profiler so that you get a full overview where time is spend.

Comment: My image is much larger than 4x4. Also 60Hz is the base frame rate, but I need to be able to speed that up by 2, 4, or more, while still getting a smooth rendering. From the profiler, most of the time is spent on the method `setRGB` of the class `BufferedImage` in the nested loop (setting each pixel individually). I was wondering if using directly a color array could improve performances, hence my question.

Comment: What kind of performance numbers are you getting now?  Are you failing to meet your performance requirements?  If you need to do 60 frames/sec and you're getting 52, optimization tweaks like you're asking for are a possible solution.  If you need to get 240 frames/sec and you're getting 2, optimizations like you're asking for probably won't be anywhere near good enough and you'll likely have to solve the problem in some other way, such as using a different algorithm entirely, redesigning your application to create new frames in parallel, or even buying faster hardware.

Comment: (cont) So any answer that you would find usable in your situation depends on how much faster you need to go.

Answer (score 0):

The nested loop over x=0..3 and y=0..3 can be rewritten to a loop of i=0..15.
The variables x and y are then calculated as:

- `x = i % 4`
- `y = i / 4`

As the array dimensions are **powers of 2**, this simplifies to the faster operations:

- `x = i & 0b11`
- `y = i >> 2`

Ideally, the indices would then also be a one-dimensional array. This would look like this:

```
int[] COLOR_MAP = new int[]{0xFFFFFF, 0xD3D3D3, 0xA9A9A9, 0x000000};
int[] indices = new int[]{
        0, 1, 2, 3,
        3, 2, 1, 0,
        2, 1, 3, 3,
        1, 1, 2, 2,
};
int[][] colors = new int[4][4];

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    colors[i >> 2][i & 0b11] = COLOR_MAP[indices[i]];
}
```

Comment: One of the optimization the JIT applies is strength reduction. So it will replace expensive operations by cheaper ones with the same effect. So probably a good thing to run a microbenchmark and check if it actually makes a difference.